# Electron framework window management for refresh not working

Tags: electron

i've created a program in electron where:
When i a button in one window sends a ipc to the main window and check if the window exist and refresh the window, but its not working.
Maybe i missed something in the documentation but i don't find anything about how to check if a window is null or undefined (Already tried to check if is null and others none values).
Thanks for the attention.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcFx9.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NaQE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a scope issue. Please ensure the window variable is reachable by your code. Something like this should work:

```
var mywindow = null; //global def

app.once("ready", function() {
  mywindow = new BrowserWindow({...});
  mywindow.loadURL(...);
});

ipc.on('something_refresh', function(evt) {
 mywindow.reload(); //this works for me
});
```

Comment: I just don't believe how dumb i am, ty it just worked fine.